# select login page for forms authentication based on custom rules

Tags: asp.net, authentication, forms-authentication

i have a web site that uses forms authentication. the problem is that i have the site installed multiple times on the same production servers because i need to have a few different login pages (based on the domain in this case). after the domain specific login page, the rest of the site is the same. obviously, this requires a lot of maintenance as each new version has to be installed multiple times on the server (with varying the login page in the web.config file).

so i thought is there a way to install the site on 1 folder on the disk, have a web site on the IIS take in all the needed domains and make some http module (or some other solution) in which i could give it a list of domains and the forms authentication for that domain. this way make the login page used by each site change according to the domain while still having only one site to maintain on the server.

Thanks
Dani Avni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this go a number of ways and a lot of it depends on how you have things setup in IIS.

If all domains are on the same IIS website the most common solution would be to create a httpmodule, or even an actual .aspx page, that loads configuration and based on the requested URL send the user to the right login page.  You could even do a "Server.Transfer()" if you want the users URL to stay the same.   Then in the web.config you still set a single login page.  Just make sure that each other login page allows anonymous users access.

If all domains are separate IIS sites, i would recommend at that point just maintaining different copies of the sites.  But the real question is why you need different logins.

Comment: the reason i need seperate logins is because although i have one system i have a few partner resellers each wanting their own logon for the customers they sold to.

Comment: i will use a single logon page that will decide which login page needs to be rendered and use server.transfer to render that page.

Comment: After testing this approach, it does not work. I created a redirector login.aspx page and in it i have put a simple server.transfer("ActualLogin.aspx") call to one of the login pages.  At first the login failed because I was trying to post data to ActualLogin.aspx which is not permitted since the user was not logged in yet and the ActualLoginPage.aspx is therefore protected by the forms authentication. So I changed the action on the ActualLoginPage.aspx form to submit to Login.aspx which still doesn't work but now I just don't get the events of the logon button that was clicked on the browser

Comment: You must ALSO allow access to each login page to ALL users.

Answer (score 0):

My workplace has a couple of web applications that do exactly what you are trying to describe.  There are a couple of approaches we have used, depending on the situation.

The more common approach we use is to have all the actual sites on IIS point to the same directory.  The logic for the login gets the URL, determines which client site is being requested, and takes that into account on login.  The actual login page is the same for all client sites, though, so it's just determining which database to use.

If you want to do anything fancier than that, another approach we have used is to create our own `MembershipProvider`, at which point you can basically do whatever you want.  You should have access to `HttpContext.Current` if your class is being called by the ASP.NET authentication provider (you would set the membership provider in Web.config to your provider).